# How to refresh items in Qcombobox [python]?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a list of data which is shown in the Qcombobox (using 'addItems')
Now - if the list is changed by loading data from a file with pushbutton - i don't see the new data in the combobx.
The new data is there (I can print it after loading)
What do I miss?
below is the code for the simplified gui

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QFileDialog
import pandas as pd

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.comboData=['None']

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(456, 172)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))

        self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 60, 69, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox"))
        self.comboBox.setEditable(True)
        self.comboBox.addItems(self.comboData)

        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 60, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.load)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 456, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Load", None))

    def load(self):
        fileName=QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(MainWindow,'Load File')
        data_pd=pd.read_csv(fileName,index_col=0,na_filter=False)
        self.comboData=list(data_pd.var1)
        print(self.comboData)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you only load the data to `self.comboData` but do not load them to `self.comboBox`.
At the end of

`def load(self):`

add the following lines:

```
self.comboBox.clear()       # delete all items from comboBox
self.comboBox.addItems(self.comboData) # add the actual content of self.comboData
```

As the model used by `QComboBox` emits the `dataChanged()` signal whenever the data in an item are changed, the combobox is repainted automatically and it is not necessary to update the combobox by

```
self.comboBox.update()
```